# Winpcap - pcap_next_ex vs pcap_loop

Tags: c++, c, handler, pcap, winpcap

I have a question, Imagine I have a thread which captures packets and process them itself.

With `pcap_next_ex`: I would use a loop and I would process the packets in each interaction, suppose I call `Sleep(200)` to simulate the stuff. With `pcap_next_ex` I would arrive a moment when I would lose packets.

With `pcap_loop`: I would use a callback to a packet handler for each packet incoming it would work like an event. In the packet handler I would treat the packets and suppose I call `Sleep(200)` to simulate the stuff. Would I lose packets?.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

`pcap_next_ex` and `pcap_loop` call the same internal function that reads a packet from the ring buffer. The difference is only that the former return the packet but the latter calls a callback with the packet.

`pcap_loop` calls the callback in the same thread as one called the `pcap_loop`, and waits for the callback to complete its task before reading the next packet.
So, if the callback takes a long time, the `pcap_loop` cannot read packets enough frequently, which results in more possibility to lose packets.

Comment: I would like that you would see a code I have which generates me problems doing a NAT with winpcap to a proxy local server. Im new in the community I would like to give you a PM. Regards.

Comment: Ok. My contact is kaitoy@pcap4j.org

Comment: Thank you for your contact, I will write you my question as soon as I have time to create it, maybe I publish it in stackoverflow, I will keep you informed regards :)